# Confused about signature creation process (in GoLang)

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

I am trying to making my own signature system, just for the challenge sake. I have done like 3/4 of it.

Canonical string and String-to-sign is matching with what they except, so I will only post my signature calculation part.

```
signature := hmac.New(sha256.New, kSigningSum)
signature.Write([]byte(stringToSign))
signatureSum := signature.Sum(nil)
var signatureSumHexed = make([]byte, hex.EncodedLen(len(signatureSum)))
```

I am trying to set kSigningSum as key, and stringToSign as value, as its documented.
kSigningSum:

```
    kSecret := AppCred.IAMSecretAccess
    kDate := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte("AWS4"+kSecret))
    kDate.Write([]byte(time.Now().UTC().Format("20060102")))
    kDateSum := kDate.Sum(nil)
    kRegion := hmac.New(sha256.New, kDateSum)
    kRegion.Write([]byte("us-east-1"))
    kRegionSum := kRegion.Sum(nil)
    kService := hmac.New(sha256.New, kRegionSum)
    kService.Write([]byte("execute-api"))
    kServiceSum := kService.Sum(nil)
    kSigning := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte("aws4_request"))
    kSigning.Write(kServiceSum)
    kSigningSum := kSigning.Sum(nil)
```

this is basically

> kSigningSum = HMAC(HMAC(HMAC(HMAC("AWS4" +
> kSecret,"20150830"),"us-east-1"),"iam"),"aws4_request")

AuthHeader:

```
var authHeader = fmt.Sprintf("AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=%s, SignedHeaders=%s, Signature=%x, X-Amz-Date=%s", AppCred.IAMClientID+"/"+credentialScope, signedHeaders, signatureSumHexed, GetTime())
```

I cant understand what I am doing wrong. stringToSign is String-to-sign and it is correct, 1:1 match with what Amazon expects so data is correct. There is something wrong with kSigningSum and cant understand it. help?

Comment: AppCred.IAMClientID and AppCred.IAMSecretAccess is the IAM user's ID and secret.

Comment: I think It should be ```signatureSumHexed := hex.EncodeToString(signatureSum)```  not `var signatureSumHexed = make([]byte, hex.EncodedLen(len(signatureSum)))`